# How to write controller to activate Blender Game Engine actuator?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I am new to Blender and but working on some simulation which involves Blender Game Engine. I want my mesh to follow a path while in motion. For that I am doing the following:

- create a KX_SteeringActuator
- configure it on PATHFOLLOWING
- configure velocity, acceleration, turn speed
- potentially setting target and navigation mesh (checking selfterminated)

So my python script has some code like below:

```
actuators['Steering'].behavior = Path_following
actuators['Steering'].velocity = 3.000
actuators['Steering'].acceleration = 3.000
actuators['Steering'].turnspeed = 120.000
actuators['Steering'].distance = 1.000
actuators['Steering'].target = target
actuators['Steering'].navmesh = navMeshWhole
```

Now, I can not figure out how do I activate the above actuator, so that my mesh object starts moving towards the target. I want to have a python controller for the above Actuator. If any one has idea or dealt with similar problem, please guide me. I want to write a python controller to activate this actuator.

--> If I have a Keyboard sensor, linked with an And controller which is linked with the above actuator then, if Game Engine started (pressing p in blender), it gives desired behavior on the Keyboard-Sensor key-press. The mesh object navigates towards the target object, following the path. Dont want to use Keyboard sensor and And controller. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I could manage to solve it. I used a property sensor and activate it using some object property. And then, while game engine running, I dynamically change the object property value. Like "0" for making the mesh move forward and "1" for backward and so on. I used MeshName['PropertyName'] = 0 or 1. So, if it is set to 1 then sensor gets active and propels my mesh. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can controller.activate(actuator) like this:

```
logic.getCurrentController().activate(actuators['Steering'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

- Create an ALWAYS sensor (*Check the 'True' box for the script to run constantly*)
- Create a AND and PYTHON controller
- Create a STEERING actuator

Connect all;

[image]

Now just set it up with the python script.

See some commands from this actuator:

```
# Get controller
cont = logic.getCurrentController()

# Get scene
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()

# Current object
own = cont.owner

# Get the target to follow on the scene
varTarget = scene.objects['objTarget']

# Variable that receives 'actuator steering'
varSteering = cont.actuators['Steering']

# Definitions of actuator

# Target object
varSteering.target = varTarget

# Detection distance
varSteering.distance = 10.0

# Movement speed
varSteering.velocity = 3.0

# Mode of behavior
# 1=SEEK, 2=FLEE, 3=PATHFOLLOW
varSteering.behavior = 1
```

You can get everything about the steering actuator in https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bge.types.KX_SteeringActuator.html#bge.types.KX_SteeringActuator